# Javascript POO : it is possible to put a object method in an onclick?

Tags: javascript, methods, event-handling

I want to put a object method in a onclick, but my code doesn't work.

Here the code, very simple :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//The constructor :
function Foo()
{   
    /*Create a div element and add it to the document :*/
    div_element = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.insertBefore(div_element, null);

    /*Create a method for hidding div element :*/
    this.hide = function()
    {
        div_element.style.display = "none";
    }

    /*Insert button inside the div element. This button contains the method this.hide() in an onclick for hidding the div element :*/
    div_element.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Hide" onclick="this.hide();">';
}

foo = new Foo();

</script>
```

But the method this.hide() in the button doesn't work.You can try the code here : https://jsfiddle.net/0s5smd52/

Have you an idea ?

Thank you in advance, cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hide()` function is scoped to your `Foo()` object. If you add it to the input in the manner you are now, it's being interpreted in the global scope and `this.hide()` will effectively mean `window.hide()`, which doesn't exist.

The solution to this is to create your new input, set the onclick handler, then add it to the DOM.

Also, use `var` in front of your variables so that they don't pollute the global scope.

```
function Foo()
{   
    var div_element = document.createElement('div');

    this.hide = function()
    {
        div_element.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // create hide button
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = 'Hide';
    btn.onclick = this.hide;

    // add it to the div
    div_element.appendChild(btn);

    // add everything to the DOM
    document.body.insertBefore(div_element, null);
}

foo = new Foo();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, my code is more complexe, because the div element must contains others html stuffs : 

div_element.innerHTML = '<div></div>...<img src="..." style="...."><div></div>...", 

so if I want to add onclik="this.hide();" in the img tag above, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in `this.hide()` is a reference to `div_element` not `foo`.

In order to call the method `hide` after a click, you need to use closure, global variables, or the method bind.

In your code `foo` is a global variable so `foo.hide()` should work.

Comment: Yes, but I want put `this.hide()` in an onclick inside a html tag (for example img tag) which is inside a innerHTML 

`div_element.innerHTML = '<div></div>...<img src="..." style="...."><div></div>`

Comment: If foo is a global variable than onclick="foo.hide()" should work, if foo is not a global variable, then the code you put in the onclick needs some way of getting a reference to foo. Also after you set a value to innerHTML you can use DOM to get a reference to the tag and then add a handler to the click event.